# Angular - Parent with ngFor waits for child to click before moving onto to new item in ngFor

Tags: angular, parent-child, parent

My question is how to force the following item in the list to wait for the child button to be clicked.
I won't include all the mistrials that I have tried......

This is the parent component code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  mockData = ['Curly', 'Moe', 'Larry', 'Shemp'];

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

This is the parent html code:

```
<app-child *ngFor="let name of mockData" [name] = name></app-child>
```

This is the child typescript code:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onClick(): void {
    console.log(`${this.name} has been clicked`);
  }

}
```

This is the child html code:

```
<div>
  <p>{{name}}</p>
  <button (click) = onClick()> Wait for Me to Click</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you want the child component to render when the button in child element is clicked?

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to just display Curly with a button, once that was clicked for the for loop to move to the next entry and only display Moe with a button.  Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

**Parent HTML**

```
<app-child *ngFor="let name of mockData" [name]=name (childClicked)="onChildClicked($event)"></app-child>
```

**Parent TS**

```
onChildClicked(name: string): void {
    console.log('child ' + name + ' was clicked.');
}
```

**Child TS**

```
@Output() childClicked: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

onClick(): void {
    this.childClicked.emit(this.name);
}
```

**Child HTML**

```
<div>
  <p>{{name}}</p>
      <button (click)="onClick()">Wait for Me to Click</button>
</div>
```